# SQL Server - Unexpected behavior with ISNULL/NULLIF

Tags: sql-server, isnull

Trying to understand the reason for the below behavior in SQL Server.

The below expression returns '*' on my server:
`Select IsNull(NullIF(RTrim(NULL), '  '), '**')`

Shouldn't it be returning '**'?

If I use any of the below statements instead, it correctly returns  '**'.

1. Using `sql_variant` variable for `RTrim(NULL)`

`declare @a sql_variant = RTRIM(NULL)
Select IsNull(NullIF(@a, '  '), '**')`

2. Using a `char(2)` variable

`declare @a char(2)
Set @a = NULL
Select IsNull(NullIF(RTrim(@a), ' '), '**')`

SQL Version: SQL Server 2008 SP3
ANSI Settings: Default SSMS settings.

Comment: If you used coalesce here it would work as you expect. This is because coalesce will use the highest datatype but isnull uses the datatype of the first value. And since you threw RTRIM around NULL it will assume the datatype is varchar(1).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because your *`NULL`* has no initial data type, thus, when SQL Server converts it to a `varchar`, it effectively converts it into `varchar(1)`. Hence the value returned is only `'*'`.

To get the expected behaviour you need to let SQL Server know what the data type of the *`NULL`* is. For example, by declaring a variable (as you did) or use `CAST` or `CONVERT`:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(2) = NULL;

SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(RTRIM(@String), '  '), '**');
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(2),NULL)), '  '), '**');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because only the first character is returned at your query since there is no initial data type for the parameter `null`. Try:

```
Select IsNull(NullIF(RTrim(cast(NULL as varchar(max))), '  '), '**')
Select IsNull(NullIF(RTrim(cast(NULL as varchar(max))), '  '), '*****')
```